# mapStateToProps state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I have a state undefined problem within mapStateToProps which literally drives me crazy.
There are a lot of undefined problems topics within Stackoverflow but the code that I am using fits all criteria so far but still gets undefined.

My code is based on https://github.com/JulianCurrie/CwC_React_Native/tree/redux_tutorial

I am using the new version of React native and Redux.
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5"

These are files.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

import configStore from './app/store';

const store = configStore();

const TestApp = () =>
<Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
</Provider>

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => TestApp);
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Button,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {createChat} from './app/actions/chat'

const addItem = () => {
  this.props.add('Add Content MSG');
}

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>{this.chats.length}</Text>
        <Button onPress={addItem} title="Add Msg"/>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    chats: state.chatReducer.chatList
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    add: (data) => dispatch(createChat(data))
  }
}

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps,mapStateToProps)(App);
```

app/actions/chat.js

```
import {CREATE_CHAT,DELETE_CHAT} from './types';

export const createChat = (data) => (
    {
        type: CREATE_CHAT,
        data: data

    }
);

export const deleteChat = (key) => (
    {
        type: DELETE_CHAT,
        key: key

    }
);
```

app/store.js

```
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import chatReducer from './reducers/chatReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    chatReducer:chatReducer
})

const configureStore = () => createStore(rootReducer);

export default configureStore;
```

app/reducers/chatReducer.js

```
import {CREATE_CHAT,DELETE_CHAT} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    chatList: [],
}

const chatReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {


    switch(action.type){
        case CREATE_CHAT:
           return {
                ...state,
                chatList: state.chatList.concat({
                    _id:  Math.random().toString(12).substring(0) ,
                    text: action.data,
                    createdAt: new Date(),
                    user: {
                      _id: 1,
                    },
                    sent: true,
                    received: true,
                    pending: true,
                  })
            }

        case DELETE_CHAT:
            return {
                ...state,
                chatList: state.chatList.filter((item) => 
                item.key !== key)
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
    

};

export default chatReducer;
```

app/actions/types.js

```
import {CREATE_CHAT,DELETE_CHAT} from './types';

export const createChat = (data) => (
    {
        type: CREATE_CHAT,
        data: data

    }
);

export const deleteChat = (key) => (
    {
        type: DELETE_CHAT,
        key: key

    }
);
```

app/actions/types.js

```
export const CREATE_CHAT = 'ADD_CHAT';
export const DELETE_CHAT = 'DELETE_CHAT';
```

this.props somehow doesnt work either, its really frustrating as there are many diffrent versions of implementations within redux.

I really hope that someone know how to fix this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have arguments in the wrong order.

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);`

Comment: I really noobed this one, Thank you for your fast response and correct answer much appreciate :).

Answer (score 0):

you are not using `props`,

you might get your data from your props like below :

```
const App: () => React$Node = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>{this.props.chats.length}</Text>
        <Button onPress={addItem} title="Add Msg"/>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};
```

`mapStateToProps` is responsible for passing data of redux store to your components `props` via `connect` function!

Comment: thank you for your fast response, much appreciated. I already Tried this but it still gives me undefined _this.props . Are there any workarounds ?